# casperjs test cow-test.js undefined not a function evaluating casper.test.begin

Tags: testing, undefined, casperjs

I am using Windows.
I am trying to use the CasperJS test framework.

I am using phantomjs version 1.9.0.
I am using casperjs version 1.0.2.

When I run

```
casperjs test cow-test.js
```

The following is returned.

```
Test file: cow-test.js
FAIL TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.test.begin')
#    type: uncaughtError
#    error: "TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.test.begin')"
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'casper.test.begin')
  C:/cow-test.js:16
FAIL 1 tests executed in 0.116s, 0 passed, 1 failed.

Details for the 1 failed test:

In cow-test.js:0
   uncaughtError: TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function 
   (evaluating  'casper.test.begin')
    var cow = {};
    test.assert(cow);
    test.done();
})')
```

If I do only

```
console.log(casper.test);
```

The following is returned

```
[object Object]
```

If I do only

```
console.log(casper.test.begin);
```

The following is returned.

```
undefined
```

What do I do?
Do I supposed to run "casperjs test cow-test.js" from a specific directory?

Or, something else?

Thanks,
Andre
Andre_Mikulec@Hotmail.com

Answer (score 7):

You using stable version of casperjs while docs and code on site are for devel [version 1.1](http://docs.casperjs.org/en/latest/upgrading/1.1.html)

Comment: yes, exactly, I had the same. Stick to 1.1 (currently it's 1.1.0-DEV) and it'll all run perfectly.

Answer (score 4):

the "test" API is introduced only since casperJs 1.0.2, you should upgrade 
to use this syntax.

For support, CasperJs have an mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/casperjs

With hope it helps,